# How to change Background image on image hover using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a small collection of background images I want to set background image to the image user hovers I have created this but its not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').mouseover(function(){
var pic=$(this).attr("src");
$('body').css('background','url(pic)');
})
});
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: You should concatenate the strings, `'url(' + pic + ')'`.

Comment: First off- `$('body').css('background','url(pic)');` will do nothing - you meant `$('body').css('background-image','url(' + pic + ')');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate variables from string using `+`

**try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').mouseover(function(){
var pic=$(this).attr("src");
$('body').css('background-image','url('+pic+')');
})
});
```

or simply

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').mouseover(function(){
$('body').css('background-image','url('+$(this).attr("src")+')');
})
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').mouseover(function () {
        var pic = $(this).attr("src");
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + pic + ')');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FGRbz/49/)**